# Avoid Multiple nested if statement in C

Tags: c, if-statement, for-loop

I'm thinking to avoid the nested if statements occur in my code.

```
for (i = 0; i < N; i++) {
  if(x & y != 0) {
     if(z & k ==  z) {
        if(w & ( (c || u) && f)) { 
            //  Do something with the checked condition
        }
      }
    }
 } 
             `
```

First The for loop and then inside multiple if statements looks ugly . Also the values x, y , z, k etc are of form edgeBag[i].edgeWeight or even larger than that in width hence it looks more ugly.

One way i can think is to use variable to store the x, y, z etc and then use the variable inside the if statement to check the condition.

```
 for (i = 0; i < N; i++) {
 a = x;
 b = y; 
 ...
   if(a & b != 0) {
       ...
          ...
           // .....
    }
  }
```

In beginning i was not very annoyed by this but once this pattern started to occur very often it's annoying. Is there any way to avoid this pattern. Or a better way to state that. Thanks.

Comment: Are there also `else`s? Why not just `((x) & (y) != 0) && ((z) & (k) ==  z) && ((w) & ( ((c) || (u)) && f))`?

Comment: It might look less ugly if you didn't use so many unnecessary parenthesis!!

Comment: The point is John x, y,z etc are long in nature hence its looks worse and if i do it using variables it looks less readable.

Comment: () was used to show that its not a just a binary number.

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
for (i = 0; i < N; i++) {
  if(x & y == 0) continue;
  if(z & k != z) continue;
  if(!(w & ((c || u) && f))) continue;
  //  Do something with the checked condition
}
```

You could also `||` the ifs together.

Comment: Thanks zenith it's better. What's the standard practice ?

Comment: @user2754673 Unfortunately no "standard" practice concerning this exists.

Comment: @user2754673 If you might ever end up having to add an 'else' to any of your if's in that loop, then I'd suggest you use your original code.